# How to use divs as radio button selectors for hidden field with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button, hidden

I'm trying to create a good looking product order form with jquery skills.

I have some shoe size values as like divs:

```
<div id="select-size">
    <div id="size-value-19">39</div>
    <div id="size-value-20">40</div>
    <div id="size-value-21">41</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="option[229]" id="option-size" value="">
</div>
```

When a customer clicks on a shoe size numbers it should take the size-value-**??** part from div id and put it into #option-size hidden field.
How can I do that?

BTW: I had found a prototypejs example for this work but prototype and jquery can't work together properly.
Let me give the prototype example code for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    function deActivate(elt) {
    elt.removeClassName('active');
    }
    function watchClick(evt) {
    var element = Event.element(evt);
    if (element.hasClassName('outstock')) return;

    $$('#select-size div').each(function(elt) {deActivate(elt)});
    element.addClassName('active');
    var eid = element.id.split('-')[2];
    $('option-size').setValue(eid);
    }
    $$('#select-size div').invoke('observe', 'click', watchClick);
});
//]]>
</script>
```

I still can't believe that how js framework developers use same $ sign...

Comment: is it giving errors when using prototypejs. please provide code or be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code presented by OP, translated to jQuery:

```
$(function() { // On DOM ready ...
    var $sizes = $('#select-size div'), // Size elements
        $input = $('#option-size'); // Hidden input

    $sizes.click(function() { // On click on size element ...
        var $this = $(this); // Reference to this element
        if (!$this.hasClass('outstock')) { // If not out of stock ...
            $sizes.removeClass('active'); // Remove .active on all
            $this.addClass('active'); // Add .active on this

            $input.val(this.id.split('-')[2]); // Set value in hidden field
        }
    });
});
```

([Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/5KfZD/2/))

**On a general note:**
You should be able to suppress jQuery's use of the `$` symbol via the [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) setting. However, it is advisable to translate the functionality into jQuery if this library is already present *and* you have no other use for prototypejs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').click(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('#option-size').val(id);

});
```

Comment: it will add click function to all div  tag in page

Comment: @DeveloperX , if you have hundrad divs what will you do ??

Comment: @DeveloperX , according to the question . i think my answer is correct

Comment: if i have hundred of div i would find them by pattern matching with IDs

Answer (score 0):

add jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
```

and add this script to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#size-value-19').click(function () {
            $('#option-size').val($(this).text());
        });
        $('#size-value-20').click(function () {
            $('#option-size').val($(this).text());
        });
        $('#size-value-21').click(function () {
            $('#option-size').val($(this).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes , btw the  solutions that me and kanishka presented work well